# Not able to extract multiple columns using Filter Handler in Gramex

Tags: gramex

Facing an issue while fetching multiple columns using Filter Handler. Single filter for Multiple columns is working fine.

For example:

`_c=Category,country_language &_sort=Category` but if I add multiple columns with multiple filters like this `url: _c=Category&_c=country_language&_sort=Category&_sort=country_language` facing a issue

> ProgrammingError('(pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Column "country_language" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the
> GROUP BY clause. (8127) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)')')